# How does one create a coloured footnote environment?

Tags: color, footnotes

Is there any way to create coloured footnote environments?
Or to edit the footnote environment so it creates coloured footnotes?

Comment: What precisely do you mean by "colored" footnote environments -- colored letters, a colored background, or something else?

Answer (score 3):

Here I give `\Cfootnote` and `\CBfootnote` for colored footnote text and color-highlighted footnote text, respectively.  I also change the footnote number to color, but that can easily be removed, if not needed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{soul}
\let\svthefootnote\thefootnote
\newcommand\Cfootnote[2][black]{\def\thefootnote{\color{#1}\svthefootnote}%
  \footnote{\color{#1}#2}}
\newcommand\CBfootnote[2][black]{\def\thefootnote{\color{#1}\svthefootnote}%
  \footnote{\sethlcolor{#1}\hl{#2}}}
\textheight 1.5in
\begin{document}
This is  a test\Cfootnote[red]{Is this in red?} of Cfootnote.

And now we test\CBfootnote[cyan]{Is this in a cyan highlight?
We will make the footnote long enough so that it wraps, to verify that
wrapping works.} of CBfootnote.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to make it work for footnotes spanning more than one page? From the second page on the original footnote color is reset

Comment: @AndreasT So far, I am not able to correct this case.  I will let you know if I figure something out.