# Changes package: how to "add" a footnote?

Tags: footnotes, changes

I am unable to compile a `\footnote{}` inside an `\added{}` command. Doing the opposite (the `\added{}` inside the `\footnote{}`) does compile but doesn't produce the desired output, as I'd like that the footnote number is highlighted too to signal its addition to the text. How can I achieve this?
Thanks, Jorge.

Error I get tryng to compile `\footnote{}` inside an `\added{}`:

```
! Use of \@xfootnote doesn't match its definition.
\@ifnextchar ...eserved@d =#1\def \reserved@a {#2}
                                                  \def \reserved@b {#3}\futu...
l.20 ...ootnote\added{\footnote{With added text.}}
                                                  .
```

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=4cm,paperwidth=8cm,margin=0.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{changes}
\begin{document}

% This compiles, but doesn't yield the desired output:
Let's try adding a footnote\footnote{\added{With added text.}}.

% This doesn't compile:
%Let's try adding a footnote\added{\footnote{With added text.}}.

\end{document}
```

Result (undesired -- need footnote number also highlighted!):

[image]

Comment: ...maybe it has something to do with a missing parameter to a macro, as dealt-with here?: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60299/a-doesnt-match-its-definition-problem-that-i-dont-understand

Answer (score 2):

The changes package does not take into account that the number of a footnote has to get a different color, if changed.

There have been some questions about colored footnotes, e.g. see here: [Change the color of footnote marker in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26693/4736) or here: [How does one create a coloured footnote environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/220456/4736)

I found a package (footnotehyper), which provides a kind of colouring footnotes, but the footnote numbers in the foot of the page are not being colored.

Is your whish really worth much time and effort?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Keks. While it may seem like a menial detail (which might be solvable through alternate means), I do believe the correct behavior of the package would be to highlight the footnote symbol(number) as part of the change, since, strictly speaking, it *is* part of the added text. But I guess that's for future improvements to the package. For the time being I guess I'll leave it like this...