# Changes package: how to “delete” a footnote?

Tags: footnotes, changes

I am [again](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/434833/changes-package-how-to-add-a-footnote) facing an issue with the changes package regarding footnotes: is it possible to somehow use it to mark the deletion of a footnote? If I use the code below, the final version still features the footnote. How can I get rid of it, while still being able to highlight its deletion (in the non-final version)? 
Thanks, Jorge.

**Example:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=4cm,paperwidth=8cm,margin=0.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{changes}
%\usepackage[final]{changes}

\begin{document}

% This compiles, but doesn't yield the desired output:
Let's try deleting a footnote\footnote{\deleted{Which had some text.}}.

% This doesn't compile:
%Let's try deleting a footnote\deleted{\footnote{Which had some text.}}.

\end{document}
```

**Output (non-final left; final right):**
[image]

Answer (score 3):

You have the `\deleted` command inside the command footnote. But this way the footnote will remain there and will be empty after selecting `filal` option of changes.

The (boolean) variable that shows if the version is draft is named `Changes@optiondraft` and also the package `ifthen` is loaded.

So, my idea is to define a command `\deletedfootnote` and when you want to delete a whole footnote, add `deleted` word before the footnote of the command `\footnote`
like this `\deletedfootnote`

The code is here:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=4cm,paperwidth=8cm,margin=0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{changes}
%\usepackage[final]{changes}



\makeatletter
\newcommand\deletedfootnote[1]{%
    \ifthenelse{\boolean{Changes@optiondraft}}
    {\footnote{\deleted{#1}}}
    {}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

% This compiles, but doesn't yield the desired output:
Let's try deleting a footnote\deletedfootnote{Which had some text.}.

% This doesn't compile:
%Let's try deleting a footnote\deleted{\footnote{Which had some text.}}.

\end{document}
```

Output with `draft`:

[image]

Output with `final`

[image]