# Change the color of only one footnenotemark and its text

Tags: color, footnotes

I have seen similar problems here before, but they mainly asked about how to get the coloring right for the whole document, but I just want to change the color for specific footnotes.
I think a definition of a new command is required, but I somehow do not get it to work.

Perhaps you may help me.

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}

 \begin{document}
    \color{gray!80}
    Here is some text with a footnote\footnote{... in which both number related
    to this footnote and also its text should be red!}

    Here is some more text with a footnote\footnote{... in which both number 
    related to this footnote and also its text should be black!}

    \end{document}
```

Comment: You can find the definition for coloured footnotes here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/220478/29873

Comment: Thanks this already solved the problem.